# Using bang with a scope in Rails 4 to display a 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am implementing event categories into my app, and now I have encountered the following problem. If the user inputs an existing URL (say, 'site/types/1') he will get to the desired category, however if he enters site/types/asdf (a non-existent URL) he will get an empty index page, and no error. I would like him to get a 404 or an error page, and I know that can be achieved with a bang in a controller, if using a 'find_by!' method (right?). However my query differs and I cant seem to figure out the principle.

How can I make this work with more complex queries that use scopes and lambdas? Thank you

I have the following code:

event controller

```
  def index
    if params[:type]
      @events_future = Event.future_by_type(params[:type])
    else
      @events_future = Event.future_events 
    end
  end
```

event model

```
scope :future_by_type,   lambda { order(...).where(...) }
```

router

```
  get 'types/:type', to: 'events#index', as: :type

  resources :types, except: :show
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just throw an 404 exception, Rails will redirect to 404.html automatically:

```
def index
    if params[:type]
      @events_future = Event.future_by_type(params[:type])
    else
      @events_future = Event.future_events 
    end

    #complex query here
    .......

    !@events_future.empty? || raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `type` in a RESTful way, i.e.

```
resources :types, only: [:index, :show]
```

And within your `TypesController`:

```
def index
  @events = Event.future_events
end

def show
  @type = Type.find(params[:id]) # raises RecordNotFound if type doesn't exist
  @events = Event.future_by_type(@type)
end
```

Comment: I am not using the types controller for displaying types at the moment. Actually, I wanted to avoid using it at all (with exception of creating/editing new types)

Comment: @DenisG however, fetching the type via `Type.find(params[:id])` (or `params[:type]` in your case) would solve the problem